# Silverlight Fieldset with Expander from Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, expander, fieldset, silverlight-5.0

I need to make a collapsable fieldset, that looks similar to the windows fieldset (and additional to that, it needs an arrow that expand / collapse the fieldset).

I have started to customize the template from the Silverlight Toolkit **Expander** control, but couldn't achive to get the border correctly (The text needs to be "on" the Border - as in the original windows fieldset)

Anybody done this before? Or any other Silverlight / SL Toolkit Control I should use?

This is an image of the collapsed fieldset - how it shold look like:
[image: collapsable fieldset]

Comment: What is your question? Getting stuck doesn't explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: thanks for your input. i corrected the text. my question is about how to get the border like in the original windows fieldset.

Comment: Do you have access to Microsoft Expression Blend?

Comment: yes, i have access to it. why?

Comment: Can you post an image of what it looks like and how you want it to look? Most likely you can just use Blend to edit the template to get it to look/work the way you want it to. However, hard to understand without an image since there is no border in the out of the box expander.

Comment: i have added a picture to the descirption.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [Fieldset from vectorlight](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/controls/fieldset.aspx). It's free, with source code provided.
[Here is demo](http://www.vectorlight.net/silverlight/demos/extra_controls.aspx).
Also I found a bug on this control - [solution here](http://www.vectorlight.net/forums/liquid_treeview/1503-fieldset_bug_after_disabling_enabling_the_con.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but 1.) it needs a additional DLL, and 2.) the fieldset caption is _above_ the fieldset, and not directly on the top border of the fieldset (like it is in windows fieldsets)